# MLPClassifier on time series data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, neural-network, time-series

How do I use an MLPClassifier in scikit-learn on timeseries data?

I have data currently in a list called a[]

How do I use a training mechanism to train the data in this list? It is a list that lists daily closing price of a certain equity over a period of several years.

Thanks for your help, I am still a novice in data science programming.

Can anyone please explain to me how this classifier works, whether I should use MLPClassification or MLPRegression in scikit-learn to predict the price of an equity. What exactly does the classifier do and what the different activation functions represent?

My data looks like this:

[25.45, 25.68, 25.69, 26.00, 25.70, ... etc]

These are the daily stock prices over a period of years for a stock. How could I use this data to predict the future of where the stock price will be? For example if I have 17 years worth of past data, how can I determine the next 6 months?

Comment: If you want to classify labels then use MLPClassifier. If you want to predict continuous variables then use regression . You can google both and see examples from the documentation of sklearn . If you add your data and explain your goal I could provide more information and guidance. What other information do you have for these prices ?

Comment: Hi Sera, I edited my question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use a lot of regression/prediction  methods . Search for linear regression etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general question.
You can use a lot of methods for this goal.
A simple **Linear Regression** could provide nice predictions (maybe, it needs to be tested).

A very good model that you can also use is: **Random Forest Classifiers**.

More details here [link](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/random-forests-in-python.html).

Nice example here [link](https://chrisalbon.com/machine-learning/random_forest_classifier_example_scikit.html).

**If you want particularly to use MLPRegressor, here is an example:**

**CODE**

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import random
import numpy as np


#create the model.
regressor=MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, ), activation='relu', solver='adam', alpha=0.0001,random_state=0)

#random data. let's say you have 365 values, one per day for a year
y=random.sample(range(50),365)

#make y a column vector
y=y.reshape(1,365)

#create 365 random years from 1600 to 1965
X=np.arange(1600,1965,1)
X=X.reshape(365,1)

#fit the model
regressor.fit(X,y)

#X_new is the future years. You want to predict the values for these years.
X_new = np.array([[2030,2050,2080]])
X_new=X_new.reshape(3,1)

#predict
pred = regressor.predict(X_new)

#print the predictions for year 2030, 2050, 2080
print(pred)
```

**Result**

```
array([ 265.3367414,  267.9489602,  271.8672884])
```

The first value corresponds to 2030 year etc.
For the model MLPRegressor, here [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) you can see all the available parameters.
Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I want to specifically use sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor? Could I do so with this data?

Comment: @Developer yes you can ! Do you want me to post an example ?

Comment: yes please, how do I figure out which function to use for the fit(x,y) method, where y is the function?

Comment: Y is a vector / list that contains the years of the prices. E.g if in 2010 the price was 10 and in 2012 it was 20 then X=[10, 20] and y =['2010', '2012']. I will post an example in a couple of hours

Comment: @Developer I just posted an example in which I predict values for specific years 2030, 2050, 2080. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148448/discussion-between-developer-and-sera).